# How to log django app to database

Tags: python, database, django, logging

I just wanna ask how to log all the things that is happening to my app in django. I didn't use the django admin. Instead I create an app for login and an app for my blog,comment,like/dislike. How can I log all these, like how many time this user logs in in my website and how many hours he/she stays. How many times she/he comment or like. Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried? E.g. did you google 'django logging' or 'django logging database'?

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a couple of different questions here.

**How many times the user logs in**

The easiest way to do this is to have a field in the model:

`login_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, editable=False)`

Then catch the [login signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#login-and-logout-signals) and increment that field.

**How many hours he/she stays**

This is much harder to do. You can catch the [logout signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#login-and-logout-signals) but that's not the only way you know people have left. You can use some fancy javascript to test that, maybe.

You could also monitor every hit for each user and use that. If you really want to measure this, I'd use Google Analytics or another existing javascript-based analytics engine.

**How many time they comment/like**

This is easy:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ...
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User)

number_of_posts_liked_by_user = Post.objects.filter(liked_by__id=user_id).count()
```